# To grep contents from a CSV/Text File using Autohotkey(AHK) Script

Tags: scripting, autohotkey

Can anyone please help me in writing a script in AHK based on below requirement.

**Requirement:**
I have a CSV/TXT file in my windows environment which contains 20,000+ records in below format.

So, when I run the script it should prompt a InputBox to enter an instance name.

**Example :**
 If i enter Instance4 , it should display result in MsgBox as ServerName4

**Sample Format:**
ServerName1,ServerIP,Instance1,Type
ServerName2,ServerIP,Instance2,Type
ServerName3,ServerIP,Instance3,Type
ServerName4,ServerIP,Instance4,Type
ServerName5,ServerIP,Instance5,Type
.
.
.

Also as the CSV/TXT file contains large no of records , pls also consider the best way to avoid delay in fetching the results.

Answer (score 0):

Please post your code, or at least show what you've already done.

You can use a Parsing Loop with CSV as the delimiter, and make a variable for each 'Instance' who's value is that of the current row's 'ServerName'.

The steps are to first `FileRead` the data from the file, then `Loop, Parse` like so:

```
Loop, Parse, data, CSV
{
    ; Parses row by row, then column by column in each row.
    ; A_LoopField // Current value
    ; A_Index // Current loop's index
    ; Write a script that makes a variable named with the current value of column 3, and give it the value of column 1
}
```

After that, you can make a `Goto` loop that spams `InputBox` and following a command that prints out the needed variable using the `MsgBox` command, like so:

```
MsgBox % %input%
```